# Cannot exclude pk and model from serializer in django 1.8

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I'm trying to get rid of `pk` and `model` from the output json object as part of Django serialization. I tried the below code in views.py, but it threw the below error

```
TypeError: serialize() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given.
```

To solve this, I used `@staticmethod` as well, but no much use.

Here is the **views.py**

```
def get_stats(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        srch_dropV = request.POST['srch_dropAJ']
    else:
        srch_dropV = ''
    if(srch_dropV == 'Lock'):
        stud = LockBased.objects.all()
    response_data = {}
    response_data['result'] = 'Success'
    serializer = NewSerializer()
    response_data['message'] = serializer.serialize('json', stud)
    return HttpResponse(JsonResponse(response_data), content_type="application/json")


from django.core.serializers.json import Serializer, DjangoJSONEncoder
import json

class NewSerializer(Serializer):
    def end_serialization(self):
        cleaned_objects = []

        for obj in self.objects:
            del obj['pk']
            del obj['model'] 
            cleaned_objects.append(obj)

        json.dump(cleaned_objects, self.stream, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder, **self.options)
```

Please help me to identify the issue and fix it.
I'm using Django 1.8 and Python 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

I think you confused `serializers.serialize()` with `serializer.serialize()`:

```
serializer = NewSerializer()
response_data['message'] = serializer.serialize('json', stud)
```

In contrast to the module-level function, the serializer's method does not take a target format argument, but only a queryset:

```
response_data['message'] = serializer.serialize(stud)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried using only query set - it then throws an Attribute error saying 'NewSerializer' object has no attribute 'objects'  - when for loop was being executed

Comment: Which `Serializer` class are you inheriting from? `objects` is only defined in `django.core.serializers.python.Serializer` not ``django.core.serializers.Serializer'.